# How to output/print methods with parameters in classes?

Tags: php

How is it possible to output methods in classes?

```
class Test {
    function wee($param1, $param2){
        return $param1.$param2;
    }
}
```

I want to output the method `wee` and all its content.. I also need to know the names and how many parameters the method requires

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/reflectionclass)

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Test');
$methods = $class->getMethods();
$parameters = $class->getMethod('wee')->getParameters();
var_dump($methods);
var_dump($parameters);
```

or a more stylized output

```
echo "<pre>";
$class = new ReflectionClass('Test');
$methods = $class->getMethods();
foreach($methods as $name){
    echo $name;
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hey @Mihai, you made a typo in the anchor text of your link.